What is the reason of strange gack id on package installation 831240957-607296 (-1244016517)
During our CI/CD Development pipeline one particular error is reoccuring every time pipeline is invoked

Install failed, Details: Your requested install failed. Please try
this again. None of the data or setup information in your
salesforce.com organization should have been affected by this error.
If this error persists, contact salesforce.com Support through your
normal channels and reference number: 831240957-607296 (-1244016517)

We assumed first this to be some intermittent failure that would disappear and go away but it didn't disappear and neither went away. What is this and how this can be fixed or avoided?

Opened a SF Support Case and they told me that this particular gack id is related to failed flow interviews
"This flow version is referenced elsewhere in Salesforce. Remove the usage and try again. : Flow Interview This flow version is referenced elsewhere in Salesforce"
The solution is go to Developer Console, query for
SELECT Id,InterviewStatus FROM FlowInterview WHERE InterviewStatus = 'Error' 
and delete those records manually.
